# In SQL: order unique elements by related elements timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, exists

I have two tables "loans" and "payments". Loans have a loan status and may have payments attached to them. Payments have a loan id, a overdue status and a processed date.

I want to get a list of all the loans with loan_status=1, that have at least one existing overdue=true payment, ordered by the matching payments processed date.

Below is some sample data:

```
loan
+----+-------------+
| id | loan_status |
+----+-------------+
| 1  | 0           |
+----+-------------+
| 2  | 1           |
+----+-------------+
| 3  | 1           |
+----+-------------+
| 4  | 1           |
+----+-------------+
| 5  | 1           |
+----+-------------+

payment
+----+---------+----------------+---------------------+
| id | loan_id | overdue_status | processed_date      |
+----+---------+----------------+---------------------+
| 1  | 1       | f              | 2013-07-21 07:00:00 |
+----+---------+----------------+---------------------+
| 2  | 2       | f              | 2013-07-21 08:00:00 |
+----+---------+----------------+---------------------+
| 3  | 3       | f              | 2013-07-21 09:00:00 |
+----+---------+----------------+---------------------+
| 4  | 3       | t              | 2013-07-21 11:00:00 |
+----+---------+----------------+---------------------+
| 5  | 4       | f              | 2013-07-21 06:00:00 |
+----+---------+--------------------------------------+
| 6  | 4       | t              | 2013-07-21 10:00:00 |
+----+---------+----------------+---------------------+
| 7  | 4       | t              | 2013-07-21 13:00:00 |
+----+---------+----------------+---------------------+
| 8  | 5       | t              | 2013-07-21 10:30:00 |
+----+---------+----------------+---------------------+
```

With the sql query below I can find the matching loans, however, not ordered by processed date:

```
select id from loan where loan_status = 1 and exists(
    select id from payment where
        payment.loan_id = loan.id and payment.overdue_status = 't')
```

How can I change my sql query above (or make a new one) that orders the loans by their earliest overdue payment (processed_date)?

The wanted result using the data above should be:

```
+----+-------------+
| id | loan_status |
+----+-------------+
| 4  | 1           | // 2013-07-21 10:00:00
+----+-------------+
| 5  | 1           | // 2013-07-21 10:30:00
+----+-------------+
| 3  | 1           | // 2013-07-21 11:00:00
+----+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.id, loan_status from loan_status a 
inner join payment b on a.id = b.loan_id and b.overdue_status = 't' and loan_status = 1
GROUP BY a.id, loan_status, processed_date
ORDER BY processed_date
```

Use `inner join` so you can also access the columns from the other table. (well, even if you don't need it, your query would be better if you used an inner join. What you were doing was effectively an inner join anyway)

Comment: It is almost what I want. I get the matching loans sorted by the processed date, however, if a loan got 20 overdue payments, I get 20 entries for that loan, it should only be 1 entry.

Comment: I already tried that. I get the error "for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list". Also, I assume it should be "from loan a"?

Comment: updated. can the table payments have several instances of status T for the same loan_id @MarcusPersson

Comment: If I didn't misunderstand (instances of status T?) your question, then no. A loan can have many payments aka there can be several payment instances for each loan. "loan_status" is a column in loan. "overdue" is a column in payment.

Comment: It gave what I asked for, but it didn't give me exactly what I wanted in reality. However, it was just a minor modification to fix it. I ended up changing the start and end of the query such that it looks like: "select a from ..." and "group by a.id order by min(processed_date)". Thanks for you answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select a.id, 
      loan_status,
      min(processed_date) as processed_date  
from loan as a 
inner join payment as b 
on a.id = b.loan_id 
and b.overdue_status = 't' and loan_status = 1
Group by a.id,loan_status
Order by processed_date
```

Comment: It gave what I asked for, but it didn't give me exactly what I wanted in reality. However, it was just a minor modification to fix it. I ended up changing the start and end of the query such that it looks like: "select a from ..." and "order by min(processed_date)". Thanks for you answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for overdue payments, I don't think you need the `loan` table at all

```
select p.*
from (select distinct on (p.loan_id) p.*
      from payment p
      where p.overdue_status = 't'
      order by p.loan_id, p.processed_date
     ) p
order by p.processed_date
```

If you just want status 1 loans:

```
select p.*
from (select distinct on (p.loan_id) p.*
      from payment p
      where p.overdue_status = 't' and
            p.loan_id in (select l.id from loan where l.status = 1)
      order by p.loan_id, p.processed_date
     ) p
order by p.processed_date;
```

You can use `group by` instead of `distinct on` for the logic.  However, `distinct on` let's you bring in all attributes on the row with the first overdue payment.

Comment: I'm looking for loans that have at least one overdue payment. Loans may only occur once in the list and the loans should be sorted based on their payment with the earliest processed date.

Comment: @MarcusPersson . . . I think that is what these queries do.

Comment: The ordering worked, but I think I got a list of the payments, not the loans :D

Comment: @MarcusPersson . . . These give one payment per loan (that is what the `distinct on` does.  The payment is the first that is overdue.  You can just select `loan_id` if that is the only column you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query. Above answered query will give error because for order by column name must be specify in select

```
SELECT Distinct x.id 
FROM 
(
    SELECT  a.id, loan_status, processed_date from loan_status a 
    INNER JOIN payment b on a.id = b.loan_id and b.overdue_status = 't' and loan_status = 1
    ORDER BY processed_date
) x
```

Comment: It gave me what I asked for. Thanks for you answer. :D